# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage

Tags: java, android, flutter, debugging, gradle

I am trying to build flutter apk on debug mode from android studio.

Flutter run
I get this error:

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > jlink executable /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Any solution? Same problem here

Comment: I have solved it here. Check and report if it helped you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359396/15905119 @EnzoLizama

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I solved this issue by downloading the required NDK side by side
> package as shown in this screenshot for the required SDK platform.

If you keep getting errors after doing this, please share error logs or screenshots. Thanks.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

I solved the same problem downgrading to jdk17 (from jdk21)

- install openjdk17 (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&platform=android says You may encounter problems using higher JDK versions. Jan 2024)
- change your JAVA_HOME to this version (on your .zshrc):
  `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home`
- remove gradle cache
  `sudo rm -rf $HOME/.gradle`
- perform a gradle clean to rebuild the cache (`cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`)
- build your android project
  `yarn react-native run-android` (or `npx react-native start`, then "a")

stuck 3 days with this problem 
hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error and checked the folder where the jdk is installed, for me this was `usr/lib/jvm/...` and the file `jlink` mentioned in the error message was missing. So i uninstalled the jdk with

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get clean
```

and reinstalled it with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Afterwards I checked the folder again and the jlink-file was there and it worked afterwards.

I have to mention that I do not have a flutter but a react-native project, but I think the solution could be quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is because jlink file is missing.

I had similar problem on Ubuntu and solved it running these commands:
sudo apt purge openjdk-17-jre-headless
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install default-jdk

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only need update **Android Studio** to newer version and it's working normally again.